# $X_n$ are r.v.s, is it true that $E[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E[X_n] $?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

$X_n$ are r.v.s, is it true that $E[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E[X_n] $?

My feeling is that this is not necessarily true. But cannot come up with an example.

Can someone provide a counterexample or give a proof for this statement?

Comment: where are the $X_i$ defined?

Comment: The statement is asking for any sequence of $X_n$ so they can be defined on any probability space.

Answer (score -1):

If $X_n$ are defined on the same probability space then the theorem is true and a proof is demonstrated in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9596/expected-value-is-a-linear-operator-under-what-conditions-is-median-also-a-line) question.

If $X_n$ are defined on different probability spaces then clearly $+$ must be defined on them for the question to have any meaning.

If $X$ is defined as the number of Farmer Brown's sheep in the paddock at 10am and $Y$ as the position of an electron in the CERN supercollider at the same time (for some frame of reference) then clearly it is not meaningful to speak of adding them.

Comment: Dude, it's countably infinite sum, not finite sum

Comment: The link you gave is not relevant to this question. It states the result for finite sum of r.v.s

Comment: So yea your answer is not correct

Comment: Actually it states for 2 random variables, but the sum of 2 random variables is a random variable so it can be applied over and over: that is all you need for any countable set of random variables. The sum may $\to \pm\infty$ but that doesn't matter.

Comment: "it can be applied over and over: that is all you need for any countable set of random variables." No, one needs something more, which is called Fubini theorem.